# Drag and Drop functionality in D3 tree for touch devices

Tags: jquery, ajax, d3.js

I have created D3 tree. Drag and Drop functionality  is working fine for desktop and laptop. Is there any functions for Drag and Drop in D3 to support touch devices?

D3 reference site - http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 has same issus for touch device, the drag and drop is not working with this code

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(dragListener).attr(
            "class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    }).on("mouseenter", nodeMouseover).on("mouseleave", node_onMouseOut)
            .on('click', click).attr('id', function(d) {
                return d.nodeId;
            });

dragListener = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function(d) {
        if (d == root) {
            return;
        }
        dragStarted = true;
        nodes = tree.nodes(d);
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        // it's important that we suppress the mouseover event on the node being dragged. Otherwise it will absorb the mouseover event and the underlying node will not detect it d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events', 'none');
    })
    .on("drag", function(d) {
        if (d == root) {
            return;
        }
        if (dragStarted) {
            domNode = this;
            initiateDrag(d, domNode);
        }

        // get coords of mouseEvent relative to svg container to allow for panning
        relCoords = d3.mouse($('svg').get(0));
        if (relCoords[0] < panBoundary) {
            panTimer = true;
            pan(this, 'left');
        } else if (relCoords[0] > ($('svg').width() - panBoundary)) {

            panTimer = true;
            pan(this, 'right');
        } else if (relCoords[1] < panBoundary) {
            panTimer = true;
            pan(this, 'up');
        } else if (relCoords[1] > ($('svg').height() - panBoundary)) {
            panTimer = true;
            pan(this, 'down');
        } else {
            try {
                clearTimeout(panTimer);
            } catch (e) {

            }
        }

        d.x0 += d3.event.dy;
        d.y0 += d3.event.dx;
        var node = d3.select(this);
        node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.y0 + "," + d.x0 + ")");
        updateTempConnector();
    }).on("dragend", function(d) {
        if (d == root) {
            return;
        }
        domNode = this;
        if (selectedNode) {
            // now remove the element from the parent, and insert it into the new elements children
            var index = draggingNode.parent.children.indexOf(draggingNode);
            if (index > -1) {
                draggingNode.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
            }
            if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined' || typeof selectedNode._children !== 'undefined') {
                if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined') {
                    selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
                } else {
                    selectedNode._children.push(draggingNode);
                }
            } else {
                selectedNode.children = [];
                selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
            }
            // Make sure that the node being added to is expanded so user can see added node is correctly moved
            expand(selectedNode);
            sortTree();
            endDrag();
        } else {
            endDrag();
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you manage to fix that? I'm having the same problem with on "mouseover" and "mouseout"  are not firing on the ghost circle on iPad

Answer (score 2):

The `Drag` Behavior supports clicks and touch, but in the example you give, the position of the drop is given by the `mousover` event:

```
// phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("opacity", 0.2) // change this to zero to hide the target area
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
    .on("mouseover", function(node) {
        overCircle(node);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(node) {
        outCircle(node);
    });
```

This `mouseover` event won't be triggered on touch devices.
What you can do is remove the ghostCircles, and do the computation manually in the event "drag", just before `updateTempConnector()`.

I can suggest something like:

```
var draggedNode = d;
var nodes = d3.selectAll("g.node")
.filter(function (d, i) {
    if ((d.id != draggedNode.id) && (!isChildOf(draggedNode, d))) {
        return d;
    }
    return 0;
});

var distances = [];

nodes.each(function (d, i) {
    var distanceX = draggedNode.x0 - d.x;
    var distanceY = draggedNode.y0 - d.y;                       
    var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow(distanceY, 2) );
    distances.push({
        distance: distance,
        distanceV: distanceX,   // vertical, <0 when draggedNode is above
        distanceH: distanceY,   // horizontal, <0 when draggedNode is on the left
        d: d
    });
});

// sort by shorter distances
distances.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
});

selectedNode = distances[0].d;
```

This would select (as future parent) the node which is the closest to the node dragged.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this , but no luck.  Still Facing same issues for touch device

Comment: What issues are you facing exactly ? Can you show your code ?
Btw, have you defined **draggedNode** somewhere ? I suggest to do `draggedNode = d` just before the code I suggested.

Comment: I have defined draggedNode = d

Comment: Drag and drop operations are working fine for Mozilla Firefox on touch devices. With the same code it is not working in Chrome and Internet Explorer . In Chrome I can able to Drag but failed to Drop . In interment explorer I can not Drag and Drop.

Comment: Ok. How is it with desktop Chrome in "touch device mode" ? Can you make a jsfiddle so I can try your code ?

Comment: here is link, I have copied event's code from here ( http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033  ) with the reference of this , created  tree

Comment: with desktop chrome in 'touch device'  I can drag tree node , but not able to drop that node.

Comment: What I suggested works. And I can't help you if you are not willing to answer my questions or if you don't understand them.

Comment: Have you tried this example (http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/raw/7880033/) on touch device? My code is exactly same as given here. I cannot post my code on SO.

Comment: I know this example do not work on touch device. That's why I told you how to modify it to make it work. Did you do it ?

Comment: I have tried your code and got error - TypeError: distances[0] is undefined

Comment: It's not about my code, it's about yours. Did you make a jsFiddle with your code so people can help you ?

Answer (score 1):

For the http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 example, I solved it by doing the following two things:

First: In your "drag" event add before updateTempConnector is triggered:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    goalView.selectedNode = closestNode(d);
}
```

Second: Then define the following function:

```
var closestNode = function(d){
    var ghostCircleRadius = 30;
    var nodes = tree.nodes(goalView.rootNode).reverse();
    var minDistance = 100000000; //sufficiently large number
    var returnNode = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var distance = (nodes[i].x0 - d.x0)*(nodes[i].x0 - d.x0) + (nodes[i].y0 - d.y0)*(nodes[i].y0 - d.y0);
        if (distance > 0){
            if (distance < minDistance && distance < ghostCircleRadius*ghostCircleRadius) {
                minDistance = distance;
                returnNode = nodes[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return returnNode;
};
```

This basically checks for the closest node and checks if our draggingNode is within the ghost circle radius of the closestNode.

Comment: Works well, save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

D3 [Drag Behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) automatically creates event listeners to handle drag gestures on an element. Both mouse events and touch events are supported.

> Note: Ensure that you are using latest version of D3

Comment: @Glisha Drag and Drop functionality is working for Firefox on touch devices. It is not working in Internet Explorer and Chrome. Any suggestions please

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? Try with version 3.1.5

Comment: @Glisha I am using latest version of d3 tree. 3.5.5. Its not working I am testing it on touch laptop and i pad Safari

Comment: I am referring this site http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033, this has same issue on touch device,